# How to access all 3GP audio files from SDcard

Tags: android

This is how i tried to access files from SDcard

```
// Use the current directory as title
    path = "/sdcard/";
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("path")) {
        path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
    }
    setTitle(path);

    // Read all files sorted into the values-array
    final List values = new ArrayList();
    File dir = new File(path);
    if (!dir.canRead()) {
        setTitle(getTitle() + " (inaccessible)");
    }
    final String[] list = dir.list();
    if (list != null) {
        for (String file : list) {
            if (!file.startsWith(".")) {
                values.add(file);
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(values);
```

but not getting how to display only 3Gp vales in list ,anyone suggest me to how to do it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just checking to see if the file has a `.3gp` extention?

Like:
`if(file.contains(".3gp"))`?